# Is bash support on Windows 10 is like a separate VM subsystem

Tags: bash, windows-10

Windows 10 now supports bash. I enabled it. I thought that it would be like using `git-bash` on Windows, but only natively. For example, navigating through existing Windows directory structure. However, it seems that when I run bash, it's like a subsystem, with it's own directory structure. So is bash support is like a ubuntu VM running on Windows separate from the Windows filesystem?

Comment: Are you talking about the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: @mfnalex, yeah, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Windows Subsystem for Linux, you can start bash from Windows commandline and can access your C: drive from `/mnt/c/`